# linux bash if $a equals anything then $b equals 1 but if $a equals nothing then $b equals nothing

Tags: linux, bash

default flag will always equal either nothing or [0-9], if default flag equals [0-9] then track_number equals 1 but if track_number equals nothing then track_number equals nothing

```
default_flag=$(mkvmerge --identify-verbose video.mkv | awk -F'[ :]+' '$4=="subtitles"&&/default_track:1[[:space:]]/{print $3}')
```

For some reason this does not work:

```
if [ -s $default_flag ]; then track_number=""; else track_number="1"; fi
```

Comment: "... but if track_number equals nothing then track_number equals nothing" .... Well, yeah. That's going to be true in the vast majority of computer languages you ever work with. Systems not exhibiting reflexive properties on equality are pretty rare, and somewhat difficult to work with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition is the problem:

```
if [ -s $default_flag ];
```

As per `man test`:

```
   -s FILE
          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
```

Here you are just checking for empty string so use `-z`

You can do:

```
[[ -z "$default_flag" ]] && track_number="" || track_number="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use parameter substitution:

```
 track_number=${default_flag:+1}
```

the expression on the right-hand side precisely means: "If default_flag is unset or the empty string, then the empty string, otherwise the string `1`."